# HTML Generated From XML+XSL File Not Downloading / Showing Images?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm working with TNT Express's API and I'm trying to generate their HTML documents successfully from the XML/XSL files.

We are using the following code, which then produces the HTML but I'm noticing that the images and barcode images are NOT downloading.

```
private function tnt_doc($type,$tnt_id){
        $xp = new XsltProcessor();
        $xsl = new DomDocument;
        //$xsl->load(WWW_ROOT.'tnt_files/'.$type.'.xsl');
        $xsl->load('http://iconnection.tnt.com:81/Shipper/NewStyleSheets/'.strtolower($type).'.xsl');
        $xp->importStylesheet($xsl);
        $xml_doc = new DomDocument;
        $xml_doc->load(WWW_ROOT.'tnt_files/'.$tnt_id.'/GET_'.$type.'.xml');
        $html = $xp->transformToXML($xml_doc);
        return $html;
    }
```

I see an "**ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**" error in Google Chrome when it tries to download images in the following links that are listed in the XSL file which is hosted on TNT's server.

> http://iconnection.tnt.com:81/Shipper/barcode/bc_U.gif
>
> http://iconnection.tnt.com:81/images/logo.gif

My website IP has access to connect to the TNT server or else the HTML would not load, but does anyone know why the images above are not being downloaded / included in the HTML?

Is there something we have to do this way the XSL images from TNT's server gets downloaded properly to show on my server?

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, thank you...that makes sense.  How would I go about trying to download the images from my server first before showing them in the end-user browser?

Comment: Not exactly, replace all the URLs in the generated HTML so that they go to a proxy script. Along the line of `imgproxy.php?src=http://iconnection.tnt.com:81/...` The proxy script loads the file and sends it to the browser. You could cache it on your server for performance. Make sure that you validate the URL so that it is not possible to call only specific URLs using the proxy script. Most webservers can be configured to act as a proxy, too.